# Prove that g is continuous.

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a continuous function and define $g : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  by $g(x) = |f(x)|, x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Prove that g is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

You're solution looks good. But also notice that $g$ is the composition of two continuous functions, namely $|\cdot|$ and $f$.